# "about all the types of vertebrae" or "all types of vertebrae"?

Tags: articles

I just want to say to my friend that in next class we are going to study about the types of the vertebrae.

What is more suitable to write?

> 1) "In this class we are going to study about all **the** types of the
>   vertebrae"
>
> 2) "In this presentation we are going to study about all types of the
>   vertebrae".

(By the way, there are 5 types of vertebrae)

Comment: Neither one.... If you don't elaborate on what your question (language related) is, I would say this is a proofreading question.

Comment: @user3169 thank you for your comment. Actually I didn't understand what you mean to say. This is question about the adding of the article "the". Anyway, I edited it.

Comment: Why "of the vertebrae" in the examples, but "of vertebrae" (which is correct) in the title?

Comment: Thank you. and what about the first "the" that I ask about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between *all the types* and *all types* is a matter of style, and either can be used.
However, *all the types* more specifically means "each and every type" will be studied.

> 1) In this class we are going to study about **all (of) the types** of vertebrae.
>   2) In this presentation we are going to study about **all types** of vertebrae.

In example 1, properly it would include *of*, but often it is omitted.

Also you need to use *of vertebrae* (no *the*).